# Pandas Vectorized Operation - Making counting function that resets when threshold reaches 5

Tags: python, pandas, count, cumsum, threshold

I am quite new to the programming and Im struggling to this matter. Any help is appreciated!

I have a dataframe of stocks including the prices and the signal if it will be up (1) or down (-1).
I want to count the sequence of repetition into another column 'count'.
So, when there is a sequence of **1,1,1**; then the count will be **1,2,3**.
If its **-1,-1,-1**; then the count will be **1,2,3** too.

Additionally, when a threshold value reaches 5, the counting resets. Doesn't matter if it's 1 or -1.

So, what I have is:

```
     price  sign
0    13     1
1    12     1
2    11     -1
3    12     -1
4    13     1
5    14     1
6    14     1
7    14     1
8    14     1
9    14     1
10   14     1
.
.
.
```

And what I want is:

```
     price  sign  count
0    13     1       1
1    12     1       2
2    11     -1      1
3    12     -1      2
4    13     1       1
5    14     1       2
6    14     1       3
7    14     1       4
8    14     1       5
9    14     1       1
10   14     1       2
.
.
.
```

I already have this code in normal python code.
But **I cannot do this in Pandas Vectorized Operation**!
Help me, please!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.cumcount`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.cumcount.html) by consecutive values of `sign` with modulo `5`:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(df['sign'].ne(df['sign'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() % 5 + 1

print (df)
    price  sign  count
0      13     1      1
1      12     1      2
2      11    -1      1
3      12    -1      2
4      13     1      1
5      14     1      2
6      14     1      3
7      14     1      4
8      14     1      5
9      14     1      1
10     14     1      2
```

**Detail**:

```
print (df.assign(consecutive=df['sign'].ne(df['sign'].shift()).cumsum(),
                 counter=df.groupby(df['sign'].ne(df['sign'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount(),
                 count = df.groupby(df['sign'].ne(df['sign'].shift()).cumsum()).cumcount() % 5 + 1))
    price  sign  consecutive  counter  count
0      13     1            1        0      1
1      12     1            1        1      2
2      11    -1            2        0      1
3      12    -1            2        1      2
4      13     1            3        0      1
5      14     1            3        1      2
6      14     1            3        2      3
7      14     1            3        3      4
8      14     1            3        4      5
9      14     1            3        5      1
10     14     1            3        6      2
```

Comment: This worked in the first try.
Thank you so much for the help. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

you can first create a mask when the sign shifts from pos to neg or opposite. This is to reset when the signs change.

```
mask = df['sign'].ne(df['sign'].shift())
```

Then, create a grouping variable based on the change in sign

```
group = mask.cumsum()
```

Use the group by function to do a cumulative count, here you add 1 whenever you have a repetition of the sign.

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(group).cumcount() + 1
```

Reset if it reaches five, back to 1 (hence the +1), this is the trickiest part I guess, here is a nice [introduction](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/applying-lambda-functions-to-pandas-dataframe/) to lamba function:

```
df['count'] = df.groupby(group)['count'].apply(lambda x: (x - 1) % 5 + 1)
```

And then the change of signs also resets the count to 1, which is what we identified in the beginning

```
df.loc[mask, 'count'] = 1
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, but it didn't work in my case. 
Maybe I need to configure some parts of my code.